# Bash - Reading from file descriptor twice

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-descriptors

I am working with Linux file descriptor at the moment to communicate with an external device via serial port, and I wonder if it is possible for me to duplicate the result returned the device.

In details, I used file descriptor number 5 to read and write to the serial port /dev/ttyACM0 in a raspbian device.

```
exec 5<>"/dev/ttyACM0"
```

In the background, I ran a function to continuously read from the port whenever a response was present to decide the next step.

```
function __processing__(){
   local line
   while read line<&5; do 
      ... some processing ...
      ... echo $line > "log.txt"
   done
}
```

And it has been working alright if I just sent single command to the serial port and let the background function to process the response. The issue appeared when I start working with other software to transfer data using XMODEM protocol, in the foreground.

```
sx -vv -k "./firmware_update.bin" >&5 <&5
```

The process kept timing out on ACK, despite the ACK responses recorded in the log file. So I suspected that it was because of the background process that read from FD5, leaving `sx` nothing. I then tried to remove the background process and run only the `sx` command, and my suspicion was confirmed when it successfully sent all data packages.

But then I don't have any recorded response from the serial port to actually know what to do next.

So my question is: Is there a way to rewrite the background function so that it can still read the response, without interfering with `sx`? I know that we can duplicate data from stdout using `tee` command, can I achieve something similar with FD5 instead?

*P/s: This is my first time working with file-descriptor and pipeline in Linux, so I don't know a lot of technique for redirecting output. Thank you all in advance.*

Comment: This sounds like something that would be better done with [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/) rather than bash....or, better yet, a language like python or perl that have expect-like libraries (e.g. [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/release/AUSCHUTZ/Expect.pm-1.07/view/Expect.pod) for perl, and [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) for python).   IMO, you're better off investing time into learning one or both of these general purpose languages than a single-purpose language like expect.   Also, both languages have library modules for serial communications.